# What is LIBSVM label in ARFF term?

Tags: format, data-mining, libsvm, arff

I just begin with Data Mining technique and get familiar with some data file format. I have a first look at *.ARFF and now *.LIBSVM.
Can you teel me what is the first number at the begin of line? Can I understand that number in ARFF term

```
+1 1:70.000000 2:1.000000 3:4.000000 4:130.000000 5:322.000000 6:0.000000 7:2.000000 8:109.000000 9:0.000000 10:2.400000 11:2.000000 12:3.000000 13:3.000000 
-1 1:67.000000 2:0.000000 3:3.000000 4:115.000000 5:564.000000 6:0.000000 7:2.000000 8:160.000000 9:0.000000 10:1.600000 11:2.000000 12:0.000000 13:7.000000 
+1 1:57.000000 2:1.000000 3:2.000000 4:124.000000 5:261.000000 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:141.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.300000 11:1.000000 12:0.000000 13:7.000000 
-1 1:64.000000 2:1.000000 3:4.000000 4:128.000000 5:263.000000 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:105.000000 9:1.000000 10:0.200000 11:2.000000 12:1.000000 13:7.000000 
-1 1:74.000000 2:0.000000 3:2.000000 4:120.000000 5:269.000000 6:0.000000 7:2.000000 8:121.000000 9:1.000000 10:0.200000 11:1.000000 12:1.000000 13:3.000000 
-1 1:65.000000 2:1.000000 3:4.000000 4:120.000000 5:177.000000 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:140.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.400000 11:1.000000 12:0.000000 13:7.000000
```

Why I see alot of +1 and -1 repeat in http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First number is the class label.

Comment: Can you show me some document for deatail about the format of the file?

Comment: Take a look at the README file in your libsvm installation. Basically the feature file consists of instances of: <label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2>.. The indices starts from 1, and libsvm uses sparse format where zero-valued features are not stored on file. See http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f301
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

Support Vector Machines use support vectors to represent positive and negative classes.

The first column most likely gives +1 for positive examples, and -1 for negative examples. That is why there is no other value than these two...

You may want to read the documentation of libsvm:

> Instructions for using LIBSVM are in the README files in the main directory and some sub-directories.
>   README in the main directory: details all options, **data format**, and library calls.
>   tools/README: parameter selection and other tools